# You are just bored with your job. / You just get bored with your job. (about "just")

Tags: word-order

> You **are just** bored with your job.
>
> You **just get** bored with your job.

I know that both sentences are correct, but why "just" changes its position in the sentences? How do you explain that we **can't say "just are bored" or "get just bored"**?

Comment: because just has to be put in the right place. You just are bored AND You are just bored are fine.   "get bored" takes it meaning from the phrase: to get bored, *just* must precede it. You must **just get rich** to suffer less. get rich, get sick/ill, get up, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific [rules](https://www.englishgrammar.org/position-adverbs/) about where adverbs can be placed depending on the type of adverb and what they are modifying. The adverb "just" is a type of adverb that usually has to go before what it modifies, rather than after it.

In the first sentence "just" is actually modifying the adjective "bored" and not a verb, so it goes right before "bored". In the second sentence, it is modifying the verb "get", so it goes before the verb.

As for why "just" goes with "get" but not "are" in this specific instance, there's no real rule for that, it's just convention. There are other cases where you can modify "are" with "just", but in this case some things "just are" the way they are.

Answer (score 1):

'Just' as an adverb can mean a number of different things, including:

- exactly, precisely (eg 'it is just right')
- by a very small margin (eg 'I just made it in time')
- only, simply (eg 'it's just me')

The placement is very important because it could not only act on a different word but also infer a different meaning as a result of that placement.

Saying "you *get just bored*" sounds weird because the word 'just' isn't meant to act on the word 'bored'. You're not trying to say *precisely bored*, or *slightly bored*. What you are trying to say is "you *simply* get bored".

It is different when the verb is *to be*. The adverb can't go before 'are' in your example because it is not modifying the manner of being. Again, it means "I am *simply* bored".